# Segmentation fault in malloc replication

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to implement an example from the book *The C programming language*. The example replicates a simplified version of *malloc*. My implementation produces a Segmentation fault. The functions alloc and afree are basically copied from the book. I am trying to use those functions in main. As far as I understood, the *(pointer+i) expression gives me the value stored in the address next to the pointer as long as both addresses are in the same array. It should be implicitly satisfied but obviously, it is not enough.

How can I actually use the functions alloc and afree to create dynamic array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *alloc(int);
void afree(int *);

/* RETURNS SEGMENTATION FAULT, WHY? */
int main()
{
    int *dyna_arr;

    dyna_arr = alloc(50);

    /* fill the array with integers */
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        *(dyna_arr+i) = i;
    }

    for (int i=49; i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf(" %d", *(dyna_arr+i));
    }

    afree(dyna_arr);
}

#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static int allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static int  *allocp =allocbuf;  /* next free position in buffer  */

/* alloc: return pointer to n ints */
int *alloc(int n)
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) /* is there enough space in the buffer? */
    {
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n;
    }
    else /* not enough space */
    {
        return 0;
    } 
}

/* afree: free the storage pointed to by p */
/*        Only possible in LIFO fashion */
void afree(int *p)
{
    if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
    {
        allocp = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp <= n) /* is there enough space in the buffer? */
```

your comparison is wrong.
It should be `available memory >= n` but your checking `if available memory <= n` and returning `0`;

Below modification should work

```
if (((allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) - allocp) >= n) /* is there enough space in the buffer? */
```

Comment: You are right, the comparison is wrong. I changed it, but still get segfault. Am I using the alloc function in main the right way?

Comment: @JAV Yes, I 'm able run your program without any issue.

Comment: @JAV What was the problem ?

Comment: Oh alright, my macro for compilation did not delete the old binary. Now everything works fine. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in `alloc(50);` wich gives you 50 *bytes* of memory, not space for 50 `int`. You need to use `alloc(50*sizeof(int));`.

Comment: I tried to change it, but still got segfault. But my alloc works with a buffer array defined to hold ints. So should not that be enough? By multipliing the sizeof int by 50, much more integer boxes of memory, than necessary. Or am i missing something?